# Getting a list of YouTube channel titles

Tags: powershell

What's a good way to get a list of YouTube channel videos via the YouTube API and PowerShell?

Some channels have many videos and it's sort of a hassle to scroll through the YouTube app to view them all.

Answer (score 3):

Given these two functions:

```
$api_key = 'YOUR API KEY'

function get-channel-uploads ($channel_id)
{
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod `
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=$channel_id&key=$api_key&part=contentDetails"

    $result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads
}

function get-playlist-videos ($id)
{
    $items = @()
    $ls = ''

    while ($true)
    {
        if ($ls.nextPageToken -eq $null)
        {
            $ls = Invoke-RestMethod `
                ('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId={0}&key={1}&part=snippet&maxResults=50' -f $id, $api_key)

            $items = $items + $ls.items
        }
        else
        {
            $ls = Invoke-RestMethod `
                ('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId={0}&key={1}&part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken={2}' -f $id, $api_key, $ls.nextPageToken)

            $items = $items + $ls.items
        }

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow ('totalResults = {0}   Count = {1}' -f $ls.pageInfo.totalResults, $items.Count)

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1    

        if ($items.Count -ge $ls.pageInfo.totalResults)
        {
            break
        }
    }   

    $items
}
```

We can get the list of videos for the Joe Rogan channel:

```
$items = get-playlist-videos (get-channel-uploads 'UCzQUP1qoWDoEbmsQxvdjxgQ') # Joe Rogan
```

The retrieval progress will be shown:

[image]

Now we can list the titles of the videos:

```
$items | ForEach-Object { $_.snippet.title }
```

[image]

Show titles which contain certain text:

```
$items | ForEach-Object { $_.snippet.title } | Where-Object { $_ -match 'MMA' }
```

[image]

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer